# SQLException results in onePhaseCommit failure

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, transactions

We have two JBoss-servers communicating via EJB. One of them is acting as a client.

JBoss A is acting as client.
Has no clue about any database-connections.

JBoss B is acting as host.
It is connected to the database, using hibernate.

Explanation of the problem:
A is constructing an object and sends it to B via an EJB-Call. B now needs to write that object into our database. B get's an exception because one field is too long for the database-field (we get an SQLException). B wants to do a rollback (Transaction Management).

B has the following log:

```
16:05:02,533 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (EJB default - 5) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffff0a380429:-1a12c8ea:56377a11:dd, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@370cc679 >: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1510)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:273)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.subordinate.SubordinateAtomicAction.doBeforeCompletion(SubordinateAtomicAction.java:265)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.subordinate.SubordinateAtomicAction.doOnePhaseCommit(SubordinateAtomicAction.java:235)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.subordinate.TransactionImple.doOnePhaseCommit(TransactionImple.java:280)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.XidTransactionCommitTask.manageTransaction(XidTransactionCommitTask.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.XidTransactionManagementTask.run(XidTransactionManagementTask.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3081)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3523)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:385)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:113)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: Wert zu groß für Spalte "DB"."TAB012_ACCOUNTDATA_DA_TB"."USERDESCRIPTION" (aktuell: 103, maximal: 100)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1008)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3530)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
    ... 26 more

16:05:02,549 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] (EJB default - 5) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
16:05:02,549 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 5) JBAS014255: Fehler beim Transaktionsmanagement von Transaktion id org.jboss.ejb.client.XidTransactionID@3cd94151: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.XidTransactionCommitTask.manageTransaction(XidTransactionCommitTask.java:98)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.XidTransactionManagementTask.run(XidTransactionManagementTask.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.subordinate.TransactionImple.doOnePhaseCommit(TransactionImple.java:295)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.XidTransactionCommitTask.manageTransaction(XidTransactionCommitTask.java:85)
    ... 7 more
```

A has the following log:

```
16:05:02,564 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (EJB default - 2) ARJUNA016039: onePhaseCommit on < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff0a380429:-66a054d:56377a0f:26, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0a380429:-66a054d:56377a0f:27, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=unknown eis name > (ResourceImpl{transactionKey=0:ffff0a380429:-66a054d:56377a0f:26, ejbClientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@64563f8, nodeName='hyundai149', state=null}) failed with exception XAException.XA_RBROLLBACK: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.XidTransactionCommitTask.manageTransaction(XidTransactionCommitTask.java:98) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.XidTransactionManagementTask.run(XidTransactionManagementTask.java:68) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.InvocationExceptionResponseHandler$MethodInvocationExceptionResultProducer.getResult(InvocationExceptionResponseHandler.java:99) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.24.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver.sendCommit(RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver.java:324) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.24.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientManagedTransactionContext$ResourceImpl.commit(EJBClientManagedTransactionContext.java:239) [jboss-ejb-client-1.0.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.24.Final-redhat-1]
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.XAResourceRecord.topLevelOnePhaseCommit(XAResourceRecord.java:682)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.onePhaseCommit(BasicAction.java:2270)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.BasicAction.End(BasicAction.java:1475)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:98)
at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:92) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:276) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:339) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:238) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:79) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:329) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler.access$100(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:70) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.MethodInvocationMessageHandler$1.run(MethodInvocationMessageHandler.java:203) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.subordinate.TransactionImple.doOnePhaseCommit(TransactionImple.java:295)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.XidTransactionCommitTask.manageTransaction(XidTransactionCommitTask.java:85) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.protocol.versionone.XidTransactionManagementTask.run(XidTransactionManagementTask.java:68) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    ... 6 more
```

It seems, that B delegates the transaction management to A. But A doesn't have any libs or information for the database-connection and we don't want it to have them.

Is there any way to disable the transaction management completely for A ?

Any further SQL-Statements on B result in an exception like this one:

```
16:05:58,866 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (EJB default - 6) ARJUNA016061: TransactionImple.enlistResource - XAResource.start returned: XAException.XAER_PROTO for < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff0a380429:-1a12c8ea:56377a11:e1, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0a380429:-1a12c8ea:56377a11:e5, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:jboss/DBOracleDS >: org.jboss.jca.core.spi.transaction.local.LocalXAException: IJ001151: Trying to start a new transaction when old is not complete: Old: < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=37, tx_uid=0:ffff0a380429:-66a054d:56377a0f:26, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0a380429:-1a12c8ea:56377a11:e0, subordinatenodename=1, eis_name=java:jboss/DBOracleDS >, New < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff0a380429:-1a12c8ea:56377a11:e1, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0a380429:-1a12c8ea:56377a11:e5, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:jboss/DBOracleDS >, Flags 0
at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.LocalXAResourceImpl.start(LocalXAResourceImpl.java:123)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.enlistResource(TransactionImple.java:636)
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.enlistResource(TransactionImple.java:397)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener$TransactionSynchronization.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:647)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener.enlist(TxConnectionListener.java:305)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.managedConnectionReconnected(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:467)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.reconnectManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:599)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:467)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:139)
at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:56) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:161) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:159) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1859) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1836) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1668) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374) [hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3.jar:4.2.7.SP1-redhat-3]
at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:396)
```

...

```
16:05:58,900 ERROR [stderr] (EJB default - 6) org.jboss.jca.core.spi.transaction.local.LocalXAException: IJ001151: Trying to start a new transaction when old is not complete: Old: < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=37, tx_uid=0:ffff0a380429:-66a054d:56377a0f:26, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0a380429:-1a12c8ea:56377a11:e0, subordinatenodename=1, eis_name=java:jboss/DBOracleDS >, New < formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff0a380429:-1a12c8ea:56377a11:e1, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0a380429:-1a12c8ea:56377a11:e5, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:jboss/DBOracleDS >, Flags 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A doesn't need to know anything about your database on B to run in a transaction context.

If you're using EJB they run in a transaction by default if you don't specify otherwise.

For your case one Solution is to mark the EJB in B as

```
@Transactional(TransactionMode.RequiresNew)
```

so the Method in B will be started in its own transaction, thus not influencing the transaction in A.

Also, it'd be possible to set the TransactionManagement to BEAN for A, so that you can manage Transactions yourself (and never start one)

```
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
```

As an alternative you could to the following in A:

```
@Transactional(TransactionMode.Never)
```

Comment: Setting the TransactionManagement-Annotation solved the problem. Thank you!